# Fatal error detected by the JRE - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, dll

I am getting the following error while accessing a DLL from my Java program:

```
# #A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  #EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d9df04a, pid=3696, tid=3244

# #JRE version: 7.0-b147
# #Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# # Problematic frame:
# # V  [jvm.dll+0x9f04a]

# #Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

Please suggest me some solutions to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: There are several questions about that error (some appear on the "Related" column on the right) and from what I can see, it seems the cause could be an error on the DLL itself. Could you give more information about what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to call a conversion function in DLL.

Comment: That's is still almost no information: Did you create the DLL? Can you show the code of the function? Have you called it from a different technology successfully? How are you calling the DLL (code)?